# material ui back drop is spinning in the background

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui in react js and I have a component that has some images in it the problem is when I render a mui backdrop it will run behind the pictures so no one will see it is there any solution or something?
here is my component render return block codes

```
 <React.Fragment>
                <Box m={1}>
                    <Grid container direction={"row"} alignItems={"flex-start"} justify={"flex-start"}>
                        <Grid item xs={9}>
                            <img ref={(imgEl) => {
                                this.imgEl = imgEl
                            }} src={im} onClick={this.onClick}
                                 style={{maxHeight: "90vh", maxWidth: "70vw"}}/>
                        </Grid>
                     </Grid>
                </Box>
                <Backdrop color={"white"} open={this.state.backDrop} onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({backDrop: false})
                }}>
                    <CircularProgress color={"inherit"}/>
                </Backdrop>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Do you have set a z-index on the component containing the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Backdrop` `z-index` is `-1` by default. You may opt to customize it

```
<Backdrop style={{zIndex: 2}} />
```